# Integration of css to Django templates

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I have a django project and I have added and began integrating bootstrap into my project for the base template as well as other templates that contain the content. I want to know how I can integrate custom css from within my project to finer tune my project and how I want certain things to fit together. I will add the html base template as well as the directory that contans the files to give a reference.

Here is the html files:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="{% static "static/css/main.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content" class="container-fluid">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the directory that I have for this project so you can get an idea of where the files are.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `"` quotes for path and also as you have already specified you are looking in static folder by `{% static` you only need to give path after that `static` directory.

```
<link href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: I changed the link to what you suggested and added css to the file but the css is still not showing up on my web page.... here is the html `<link href="{% static 'css/mainstyle.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">` i changed the css file name to main styles in my directory. here is the css that I have added to the file... `body {
  background-color: blue,
}` and nothing happened to my body @AstikAnand

Comment: @OmarJandali, you have `main.css` file in your project and not `mainstyle.css`.

Comment: @OmarJandali, See if you are getting your css in source.

Comment: Yes so I looked at the source and the link for css is showing up like i wrote it in the template @AstikAnand

Comment: @OmarJandali, have you tried going over that link? what it is saying?

Comment: when I click the file in the page source, it opens a black page with the css that I have inside of the mainstyle.css file. but it is just not being applied to the page. could it be the placement or something like that... the mainstyles css comes after the bootstrap... @AstikAnand

Comment: Then that's the placement issue, put your custom css at last, and then if that doesn't work try to use `!important` property.

Comment: what is the `!important` and how do i add it

Comment: @like if you are saying `background-color: red` then you can put `!important` on that so that it is prioritized. like `background-color: red !important`

Comment: it worked. thank you. but do i have to do it for every line of css... that is not fun

Comment: No, you just need to put your css files properly in order. Custom at last. And if you want to priortize something use `!important`